# How to find COUNT on a particular column in Oracle without using any inbuilt functions or any analytical functions?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

This was asked in an interview: How to find COUNT on a particular column in Oracle without using any inbuilt functions or any analytical functions?

I just heard about the `COUNT,COUNT(*)`, but we have find using these type of inbuilt keyword present in Oracle.

And that query should work for every Database like RDBMS.

Comment: Whats TCS? Your question is unclear and you should post more details.

Comment: you should not use name of the company/organisation along with their interview questions.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty stupid question to me. Using `count(*)` is typically the most efficient way of getting the total number of rows in a table.

Comment: I know count(*) is the most efficient way.But that is the Question.How to do that without them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the interview question is trying to make you think in SQL, and that maybe you have to think outside the box, ignoring the fact that `count` is standard SQL and has been for years.

Here's a suggestion, maybe something like `select rownum, * from DBTABLE order by rownum desc;` where DBTABLE is whatever table in the database you are trying to get a count from.

Of course, issues with getting all that data, maybe the number of columns in the table is huge, yada yada yada, but interviewer is looking for interviewee to think.

Comment: Correct me If am wrong, is not the query MAX (ROWNUM)?

Comment: Actually, it looks like `rownum` is only an oracle phenomenon. Maybe the OP would have to find out if the table has any sort of auto-incrementing ID column, and then do the max of that, something like `select * from Users order by UserID desc limit 1` for MySQL.

Comment: Thank you user75ponic and Philip. But we don't have to use inbuilt functions.MAX is one of them.Suppose we don;t have any Userid,then what we can do? I told them about ROWNUM. But i get no as answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Actual RowNum use is Like this:

SELECT ROWNUM, customers.*
FROM customers
WHERE customer_id > 4500
ORDER BY last_name;